# Android/Java | Wrong time string, but using correct Locale?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to get the current time, but it displays in the wrong format.
Eg. Here, it's now 00:20 and it's displaying 12:20.
What am I doing wrong?

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm", Locale.GERMANY);
Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
tv_Time.setText(sdfTime.format(today));
```

PS: I tried with

```
Calendar.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY).getTime();
```

too, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is that you didn't check [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), which is the first place you should look. Look at what hh means.

Comment: well T.T.. i'm sorry, thank you. Do you think i should even use the Locale.GERMANY thingy? I mean if i specify the Format ("HH:mm"), then it doesn't matter which Locale it is, or it does?

Comment: That depends. Having it hard-coded seems a bit weird to me, but it might be what you want. I'm not sure how Calendar.getInstance() works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`hh` uses 12-hour clock, for 24-hour clock you need to use `HH`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

If you want locale-dependent time format, use [`DateFormat.getTimeFormat()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getTimeFormat%28android.content.Context%29).